# Access a Plotly dash app alongside a React app

Tags: reactjs, flask, react-router, plotly-dash, flask-restful

I made a Dashboard using plotly Dash for my office and this Dashboard should go alongside a Digital report I made using React and plotlyjs.

Here is the structure of the website:

[image: Here is the structure of the website]

I used this [Hackers and Slackers](https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/) guide to run the dash app on flask server. I also integrated [React and Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project) successfully and was able to fetch data from flask to react and display it.

Now the issue I am facing is I am unable to access the dashapp at localhost:3000/dashapp. I was able to access the app at localhost:5000/dashapp. How can I make this accessible at localhost:3000/dashapp along with other react pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different applications, they cannot run on the same port. So one should run in 3000, and other in 5000.
However, you can have some apache configuration for redirecting the requests from browser to two different apps using one port. So, based on the configuration, if you do localhost:80/dashapp, this will point to localhost:5000/dashapp. And if you do localhost:80/reactapp, this will point to localhost:80/reactapp.

Refer to this for configuring the apache: https://geekflare.com/multiple-domains-on-one-server-with-apache-nginx/

Comment: Thanks, It is helpful. I will try that and I also want to know if this opens up any security vulnerabilities. This website is supposed to be hosted on NIC cloud which blocks public access to all ports except 80 and 443. So, in this case, when a user opens localhost:80/dashapp and it redirects to localhost:5000/dashapp would it be blocked by NIC as the port it is redirecting to is 5000?

Comment: So, this redirecting happens in the server side, it doesn't show to the end user. And other ports will not be accessible by end users, it will only be accessible by the apache server. So, security will be maintained if that is your concern.